# Ошибка в компиляции программы на Ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер

Здравствуйте. Предоставляю код простой программы на Ассемблере:

```
model SMALL 
stack 100h 
dataseg 
B dw 10 
C dw 5 
X dw ? 
codeseg 
startupcode 
mov CX, C 
mov X, CX 
;FINISH 
QUIT: exitcode 0 
end
```

При попытке скомпилировать этот код возникает следующая ошибка(предоставляю скрин ошибки):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы найти решение данной проблемы. Заранее спасибо

Comment: которая из них 14я строка?

Comment: Дело в том что тут всего 13 строк...

Comment: Возможно проблема в неправильной работе компилятора

Comment: @Вячеслав161, у меня тот же код компилируется без ошибок. Скорее всего проблема в вашем файле new.asm. Возможно какие-нибудь непечатаемые символы в конце.

Comment: @insolor а через какую программу вы компилируете если не секрет?

Comment: @Вячеслав161, все то же что и у вас - tasm, dosbox. Правда tasm поновее - версии 4.1.

Comment: я создал новый asm файл, скопировал туда тот же приведенный мною код, добавил его в папку asembler но эта же ошибка в dosbox не пропала..

Comment: может беда в редакторе? нотепад и прочие фигнню к файлу добавляют. tasm настолько древен что о таких засадах не ведает

Comment: и как тогда без notepad++ обойтись? или есть другое решение?

Comment: если  ++, то убедитесь что сохраняете простой ANSI текст